# You do not have access to this application issue in appcelerator

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy, appcelerator-studio

I am a Android developer.Now started developing android app on appcelerator titanium from Windows desktop.I am completely a beginner.
I have followed the following steps.Installed all needed software.
Imported  our existing project to appcelerator. And tried to build that project on titanium emulator from IDE. It build the project and finally shows error "You do not have access to this application". After long time emulator launches and stay without any response.

I tried the build from command line using below command

```
titanium build -p android -b
```

but it shows titanium not recognized error. Also use 'ti',then 'ti' not recognized error shows.     But my system contains Titanium.I checked it with 
"aapc info" then the result is

```
Appcelerator CLI
  Installer                   = 4.2.9
  Core Package                = 6.2.0

Titanium CLI
  CLI Version                 = 5.0.12
  node-appc Version           = 0.2.41

Titanium SDKs
  5.5.1.GA
    Version                   = 5.5.1
    Install Location          = C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win3

    Platforms                 = android, mobileweb, windows
    git Hash                  = b18727f
    git Timestamp             = 09/27/16 05:38
    node-appc Version         = 0.2.36

Intelr Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM)
  Not installed

Genymotion
  Path                        = not found
  Genymotion Executable       = not found
  Genymotion Player           = not found
  Home                        = not found

VirtualBox
  Executable                  = not found
  Version                     = unknown

Issues
  No issues detected! Your development environment should be working p
```

I have installed latest version of Node. Is there any issue with that.
Please help me detect and solve the issue.

Thank You.

Comment: please help me..

Comment: Try to build with appcelerator studio, and it's probably better if you update to last sdk (6.0.3) asap. Moreover before trying to build with cli have you logged in with appc login?

Comment: Initially I tried with appcelerator studio after login.But this shows error "You do not have access to this application".

Comment: Check on appcelerator web console if with your user you can see the app you are trying to start. As second check you can try to create a new app and to start that one, I guess that your app at the moment is not linked to your profile.

Comment: what is the reason for titanium not recognized error  while building titanium build -p android -b command.

Comment: this isn't a perfect world, try what I suggested you and if you think there is a bug report it in appcelerator's jira https://jira.appcelerator.org/